# Пути к заголовочным файлам. С++ Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qtcreator

Создал проект в Qt Creator: Проект без QT. Приложение на языке C++.

[image: Проект без QT. Приложение на языке C++.]

`#include <iostream>` - в начале cpp-файла, пишет что файл 'iostream' не найден.

как грамотно исправить эту ошибку?

Систему сборки выбрал CMake. Если сказать qmake при создании проекта, то ошибки нет. Мне нужно CMake.

Comment: в вашем Kit-е укажите  `CMake generator` соответствующий вашему компилятору

Comment: в Kit-е? Это где? В настройках не нашел такого.

Comment: @ИванКоданев Правка-Prefer.... -> комплекты Посмотрите свои настройки. Среда должна содержать комплекты (набор компиляторов для сборки проекта) если не настроен - настройте и тогда представьте сюда что говорит сборщик CMake при сборке проекта.

Comment: @ИванКоданев, imho лучше переключить creator на английский, хотя бы потому, что информации на англоязычных сайтах больше

Comment: Проблема была в том, что не был установлен cmake.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что не был установлен cmake.